# how to Create multiple controller and define them in config file in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to create multiple controllers in one custom module of me.
How do I define all of them in my xml file.

Comment: For a better help paste you config.xml and controller code in the question with proper file path.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to set the **Routes** in your config.xml file:

```
<config>    
    ...
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
    ...
</config>
```

Finally create the controllers you need in your module under the controllers folder:

```
app/code/local/Company/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php
```

For more info check this nice article:  [Magento Controllers](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world)

Comment: Hi here you create one controller indexController.php but i need to create another one controller PannelsController.php and then how to call and how to defined in config file this is

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create another controller file in controllers folder of your module like this:
Yourmodule/controllers/AnotherController.

Comment: Thanku for that but i have created another controller that is giving 404 not found error when i open in browser. can i have to define route also in config file.

Comment: here is my first and second controllers...

Comment: I think you should change your module name from PriceChange to Pricechange. Please let me know it's working or not :)

Answer (score 0):

here is my first and second controllers.

```
class YBizz_PriceChange_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'hello';  
        echo $filepath; 
    }
} 

class YBizz_PriceChange_PanelsController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    /*
    * this method privides default action.
    */
    public function indexAction()
    {
       echo 'hello panells';
       exit;
    }

}
```

and here is my config file front end

```
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <pricechange>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>YBizz_PriceChange</module>
                    <frontName>pricechange</frontName>
                </args>
            </pricechange>      
        </routers>
   </frontend>
```

How can define these controller in config file that which will be call.